# How do I cycle to the previous control in VB6?

Tags: forms, vb6

So I have a bunch of listboxes on my VB form.  I created a command button too.

I want to make it so that if I press the command button it cycles from the current listbox, which has focus, to the previous listbox.  It's the equivalent of using TAB and SHIFT TAB to cycle amongst the control.  SHIFT TAB goes backwards in the cycle, TAB goes forward in the cycle.  I vaguely remember there was a way to go back & forth in the "tab cycle".

How do I do this?

Comment: If you click a button there is no current listbox with focus as the command button has it, do you want to go back to the last box that had focus or the one before? If its the one before is it the one the user clicked on or the one with a lower .tabindex?

Comment: Hi Alex.  I want to go back to ONE BEFORE the last box that had focus...so I guess 2 controls back?..so 2 lower in the .tabindex.  I know how to give focus to the last box that had focus (before command button takes it).  Now I'm trying to figure out how to go back lower in the tabindex from that control...

Comment: I think the only way to do that would to be to track the current tabindex then enumerate controls looking for the preceeding one

Comment: Can you show me how to "memorize" the tabindex of the listbox that will have control? Then, from there, I can go 1 lower in the tabindex to activate the listbox that I really want.  Basically, I'm creating a LEFT & RIGHT button that cycles through the 10 listboxes that I have on my form.

Comment: If you have to click on a button, why not just click on the desired listbox instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can;

```
Private mCurrentListboxTabIndex As Integer

'wire up, simpler if you use a control array
Private Sub List1_GotFocus()
    mCurrentListboxTabIndex = List1.TabIndex
End Sub

Private Sub List2_GotFocus()
    mCurrentListboxTabIndex = List2.TabIndex
End Sub

Private Sub List3_GotFocus()
    mCurrentListboxTabIndex = List3.TabIndex
End Sub

Private Sub btnPrev_Click()
    FocusListBoxByTabIndex -1
End Sub

Private Sub btnNext_Click()
    FocusListBoxByTabIndex 1
End Sub

Private Sub FocusListBoxByTabIndex(offset As Long)
    Dim ctrl As VB.Control
    For Each ctrl In Me
        If TypeOf ctrl Is ListBox Then
            If ctrl.TabIndex = mCurrentListboxTabIndex + offset Then
                ctrl.SetFocus
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Alex, what do I need to do if I want the 3rd item in the listbox to be selected?